# Forking within C - infinite loop?

Tags: c, fork

Attempting to learn C forking. It correctly prints the number of times the main loop is suppose to run and the right number of threads but the execution time is off and the program never terminates. Am I making an infinite amount of processes?

After  some suggestions here is a cleaner version of the code. The old version is located below. The updated part is still creating to many child processes and never exiting. I'm just not seeing what's going wrong.

Update: Suggestion by John Hascall fixed a formatting and threads running out of order. An infinite number of threads are still generated but now in the correct order. I.e prints thread execution time 1, 2, 3, 4... etc. Don't think the problem is the wait syscall but going to study it and see if I can't find anything.

Update**: I found the solution. The first problem I believe was that I didn't have a wait command and the second is that when putting in the wait I accidentally removed the check for count < argv[1]. I put it back in and it seems to be running correctly! Thanks for the help and style pointers everyone! Working version is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "./processes.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Wrong number of arguments entered. Usage: #processes sleepTime inputFile.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if(atoi(argv[1]) <= 0){
    printf("Incorrect number of children, must be greater than 0");
    return -1;
  }

  int count = 0;
  int index;
  Child *child = malloc(sizeof(Child) * atoi(argv[1]));
  int childIndex;
  int pid;

  do{
    switch (pid = fork()){
      case -1:
        printf("Fork failed\n");
        exit(1);

      case 0:
        sleep(atoi(argv[2]) * childIndex);
        gettimeofday(&child[childIndex].endTime, NULL);
        double elapsed = child[childIndex].endTime.tv_usec - child[childIndex].startTime.tv_usec;
        printf("Time for process %d = %f microseconds\n", childIndex, elapsed);
        break;

     default: 
        childIndex = count + 1;
        gettimeofday(&child[count].startTime, NULL);
        child[count].index = count + 1;
        child[count].pid = pid;
        count++;
    }
  } while((wait(NULL) != -1) && (count < atoi(argv[1])));

  return 1;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "./processes.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Wrong number of arguments entered. Try again.");
    return 1;
  }

  if(atoi(argv[1]) <= 0){
    printf("Incorrect number of children, must be greater than 0");
    return -1;
  }

  int count;
  int index;
  Child *child = malloc(sizeof(Child) * atoi(argv[1]));
  int pid = 1;
  int childIndex;

  for (count = 0; count < atoi(argv[1]); count++) {
    if (pid != 0) {
      childIndex = count + 1;
      gettimeofday(&child[count].startTime, NULL);
      child[count].index = count + 1;
      pid = fork();

      if (pid != 0){
        child[count].pid = pid;
        printf("Main thread loop: %d\n", count);
        printf("Child process: %d\n", getpid());
      } 
    }
  }

  if (pid == 0) {
    //this is the child process
    sleep(atoi(argv[2]) * childIndex);
    gettimeofday(&child[childIndex].endTime, NULL);
    double elapsed = child[childIndex].endTime.tv_usec - child[childIndex].startTime.tv_usec;
    printf("Time for process %d = %f microseconds\n", childIndex, elapsed);

    //printf("This is thread %d reporting in.\n", childIndex);
  }

//  printf("Testing\n");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Suppose `atoi()` fails you have `malloc(0)`.

Comment: Good catch, I'll put a check in for that!

Comment: What are your arguments?  What outputs do you expect, and what do you actually see?

Comment: Use `strtol()` it let you check for errors correctly.

Comment: You should not allow both the parent and child to call `exit`. If you do, the parent's exit handlers will run twice (once in each process). Depending on what they do, this can be a very bad thing.

Comment: Currently my arguements are just 4 1 and a junk text file that can be anything. I expect it to currently print out the child number and how long it took to execute. 
For example Time for process 1 = 30 microseconds, Time for process 2 = 45 microseconds etc

Comment: Something like `if (argc != 4) { printf("usage: %s #procs waitsecs file\n", argv[0]); ...}` is more helpful than "wrong number!".

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ( i also include `-Wconversion -std=c99`) then fix the warnings. It would greatly helped if the contents of the `process.h` file had been posted. Note: when referencing a *.h file in the same directory as the *.c file(s) do not put a path on the #include statement Suggest using `#include "process.h"`

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile. Amongst many other problems, the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` is needed for the `sleep()` function. BTW: the `sleep()` function is depreciated, replaced by the `nanosleep()` and similar functions

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile. Amongst many other problems, the statement: `#include <sys/time.h>` is needed for the `gettimeofday()` function. and the proper declaration of the `pid_t` type (fork() returns a `pid_t` type, not an `int` type.

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile. Amongst many other problems, the statement: `#include <sys/types.h>` and the statement: `#include <sys/wait.h>` are needed for the `wait()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bigest issue is your child's code:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    ....
}
```

belongs in the same loop (say right after) the parent's code:

```
if (pid != 0) {
    ....
}
```

Also, you never check for `pid == -1` (the `fork()` failed).

A more standard way to write something like this is:

```
switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
         /* handle fork error */
         exit(1);
    case 0:
         /* child code goes here */
         _exit(0);
    default:
         /* parent code goes here */
}
/* Also you probably want to look into the `wait()` syscall. */
do {} while (wait(NULL) != -1);       /* <--- the very minimum */
```

Comment: Is this just a standard or does it cause problems with the code?
I was just expecting main to create all the child processes and then finish but now that I think about it does that kill the child processes as well?

Comment: Both the child and the parent return from the fork() command and start executing code right after that.  In your case all that means is the child loops through the for-loop pointlessly -- which I guess is not a huge deal, but it is surprising and surprising code is less maintainable.

Comment: Also I think this line: `printf("Child process: %d\n", getpid());` is either not what you want or nor where you want it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was for debugging purposes. I wanted to make sure that the parent was actually creating only 2 children. Turns out that wasn't the way to do it anyway.